# italian fiscal code

Tags: magento2, vat

in italy it is necessary to give your fiscal code (a code that indentify the person) when you buy something online. it is necessary for the billing.
It is possibile to add a field to magento checkout and print in on the invoice? Like the vat tax

Thansk

Answer (score 0):

you can enable vat filed using below in admin :

> Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > (Change Scope to correct website/store view) > Create New Account Options > Show VAT Number on Storefront

Change dropdown to Yes.

You'll then have to set up your tax classes/tax rules/customer groups:

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/tax/vat-validation-configure.html

Answer (score 0):

with this module you can solve also italian electronic invoice with sdi cod, fiscal code etc [Fatturazione elettronica italia Magento 2](https://www.studiograficoaltravista.com/prodotto/modulo-privatoazienda-fatturazione-elettronica-italia-magento-2/)